# Php or an alternate method to send SMS to a large group

Tags: php, bluetooth, sms

I am dealing with publicity for a particular event and i was wondering how companies managed to send large number of sms to their customers? I had come across a php script which uses free sms gateways like way2sms etc , is there anyway i can achieve this or an any alternate solution to notify a large number of people. I have also seen a few bluetooth services which notify people in a particular bluetooth region. Please give me some references i can go through to implement either a bluetooth or message facility.

Comment: There is no real alternative to using a gateway provider for sending SMS. You will need to find the best gateway provider for your country or region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of ways to do that
I'll talk from my own experience

I use [Kannel](http://kannel.org) to connect to providers using http and SMPP

Kannel will free you from managing queue (at least you have to create a db for it), it will manage connections and keep them up.
The only problem, you should have an access to *nix system, it can compile on windows but I never seen a real installation over windows

After setting up the connection with Kannel, you communicate to it using a well defined http API

The advantage of Kannel is stability with hundred of millions of messages!, yes the number is correct, I used it with more than 20 mobile company from one sun solaris box and managed into one of the links 300'000 message daily (  unfortunately the throttling stopped me from sending more :(  )

Try to find providers with SMPP links, it much more stable then http, and a system like Kannel should kill the complexities of dealing with a protocol on the low level

For the other part of the question, Bluetooth, our company was approached more that a year back from [this company](http://www.ingresqr.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=5&Itemid=34), they did a nice demo but I never worked with them directly, thought the hint may help you at least to find similar solutions

Answer (score 0):

I've only used gateway to do it.

I've used [twilio](http://www.twilio.com) service to send a large number of sms. It works pretty good and is [easy to implement](http://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries#PHP).

In the US, AT&T also has an [API](https://developer.att.com/developer/apiDetailPage.jsp?passedItemId=9700302). Never used but [doesn't seems to be complicated](https://developer.att.com/developer/apiDetailPage.jsp?passedItemId=9700302#sendsms).

And for european users, OVH also has [this system](http://www.ovh.fr/sms_et_fax/pack_sms_fiche_technique.xml). Since just came in the US, they might provide this service in the US also.

Twilio seems to be the cheapest one.

Answer (score 0):

One alternate and artisanal way to do it could be with a cellphone and unlimited sms.

For example, on a jailbroken iPhone on which you have installed sendsms package, you can make a bash script to send a large number of SMS.
The only limitation you will encounter will be how your mobile operator defines "unlimited SMS", if there is a limit with it or not.